# Flask Testing: Modify session for next request

Tags: python, testing, flask, session-cookies

I am trying to test the shopping cart part of my flask app. The test that fails is the following one:

```
# Set cart
with client.session_transaction() as sess:
    sess["cart"] = [1, 2]

# Remove item from cart
client.get("/cart/remove/2")

# Test cart
with client.session_transaction() as sess:
    resp = client.get("/")
    assert [1] == sess.get("cart")
```

The result of the last request is that the sessions still contains `[1, 2]`. I know that the actual code I'm testing works, because I've tested it manually before, so it must be something to do with how I use the session. Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure if this will make a difference... typically i use the `with client.session_transaction() as sess:` to set the session, but for your test case i would just add a `from flask import session` and `assert 1 in session["cart"]` & `assert 2 not in session["cart"]`

Comment: @abigperson I tried it and it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I was using the wrong session. Thanks to @abigperson! Fixed code:

```
def test_add(client):
    # Set cart
    with client.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess["cart"] = [1, 2]

    # Remove item from cart
    client.get("/cart/remove/2")

    # Test cart
    assert [1] == session.get("cart")
```